# Opensearch: Display nanoseconds total time in human readable form

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I'm working on creating dashboards in opensearch and I have to create a panel that displays a human readable time duration that is recorded as a large integer representing the total time in nanoseconds.
Ex: Value stored in opensearch - 90000000000000.
Value to be shown in dashboard - 1 Day and 1 hour

How can I do this in opensearch dashboards?